# Scan to SharePoint libraries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-actions

I'd like to know if it is possible to setup a scanner to send the scanned documents to different librarie**s** 
My client has a SharePoint 2013 on prem, and wants to scan a document and specify to which folder it should send. BUT if we use the email functionality, it means there should be an email address for each library (and there is more than 50 libraries)
Also once scanned the user needs to go to the library and then add the metadata, right?

The other possible option I was thinking of, is to add a 'scan' button into the banner at the top of each library.  So when you are in a library and you click the scan button, it will trigger the linked scanner to start the scan and the document will appear in that library - is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have really 2 questions.

1. emailing to the library, yes it is possible you need to set up incoming email feature in SharePoint.
2. Is it possible to trigger scan from the custom action in library. It will depend on you scanner if it has some API you could connect you might be able to achieve that but it would be best if you would post that in the specific forum for the vendor of your scanner.

Comment: Thank you Marek.  I think it would be best to go with the custom action in each library.  It will be too difficult for the user to remember each and every library's email address.  I'm awaiting to hear from them which scanner they have, and then I'll follow your advice to ask on the manufacturer's forum.